# ionic cordova build --prod --release fails and generate errors

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, apk

I am trying to build my ionic 3 project for the android platform. I am working on windows 10. When I run the following command : **ionic cordova build android --prod --release**, I get this error:

> Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Here is the screen shot corresponding to the error 
[image]

Here is the result of the **ionic info** command

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.7.0 (C:\Users\HOLLY SPIRIT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0    Cordova Platforms     : android
6.4.0    Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 22 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)    npm    :
6.4.1    OS     : Windows 10
```

And here is the content of **package.json**

```
{
"name": "app name",
  "version": "2.0.1",
  "author": "auhtors name",
  "homepage": "website url",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/admob-pro": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/browser-tab": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/instagram": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/open-native-settings": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/youtube-video-player": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angular-pipes": "^8.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.17.0",
    "cordova-android": "^7.1.4",
    "cordova-instagram-plugin": "^0.5.7",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
    "cordova-open-native-settings": "^1.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.17.4",
    "cordova-plugin-admobpro": "^2.37.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.7",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "^0.9.10",
    "cordova-plugin-extension": "^1.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.4",
    "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": "^1.0.6",
    "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "cordova-universal-clipboard": "git+https://github.com/Visigo/CordovaClipboard.git",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^5.8.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.1.0",
    "ng2-simple-timer": "^1.3.3",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.1.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.18",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "app description",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-admob-free": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "24.1.1+"
      },
      "cordova-instagram-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-open-native-settings": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "cordova-universal-clipboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-admobpro": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "16.0.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "appid",
        "APP_NAME": "237actu",
        "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
        "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "4.38.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "app reverse client id"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

To resolve this problem I tried two things:

1. I added **node --max-old-space-size=2048** in the **scripts** section of the package.json as follows:

   "scripts": {
       "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
       "build": "node --max-old-space-size=2048 ionic-app-scripts build",
       "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
       "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
       "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
     },

It did not work.

2. I edited the ionic.cmd file of my computer as follows:

   ```
   @IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
      "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic" %*
   ) 
   ELSE (
       @SETLOCAL

       @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;% **node --max-old-space-size=2048**  "%~dp0\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic" %*)
   ```

As you can notice, I just added **--max-old-space-size=2048**, but it did not work. My computer RAM is **3 984 MB**

3. I also tried to downgrade firebase to the 4 version before the build, but it did not work.
4. I updated all the dependencies of my project using this command : **npm update -f**
5. I deleted the folders from my project **plugins**, **platforms**, **nodes_modules** and i also removed **package-lock.json** from my project. And i ran the commands in the project before the build :
   **npm install**,
   **ionic cordova platform add android**.

None of theses solutions worked for me.

Any help ?

Comment: Try this [ionic-team/ionic#16868 (comment)](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16868#issuecomment-449626662)

Comment: thank  you @ViniciusLourenço but the same error is generated.

Answer (score 3):

**Finally here is the solution that have worked for me.**

The Removal of  android platform from the project with this command :

**`ionic cordova platform rm android`**

The Adding of the android platform to the project : **`ionic cordova platform add android@latest`**, in my case, i used the latest version of android platform.

The Adding of the **@angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.6.8** in the project :

**`npm install @angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.6.8 --save`**

this angular plugin will optimize the build of the project.

The running of this command in the project : **`cordova clean`**

Now when i run **`ionic cordova build android --prod --release`** it succeed.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
* add this to the package.json scripts
  `"ionic:build": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js build",`
* run the command:
  `npm run ionic:build --prod`
* run the commands:
  `cordova build android --release`
  `cordova build ios --release`
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i when i run the command :  **npm run ionic:build --prod** after editing the package.json file as you specified it above, the command never end even after 1 hour, nothing happen and no errors are displayed